# How to prompt the user after two failed login attempts in Grails Spring-Security powered app?

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

The login requirement for our Grails app is that after two failed login attempts, the user is prompted with a new question right below the fields asking if the user forgot the password.

I'm using Spring Security plugin, is it possible to code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know in the latest version of spring-security-core (1.1.3), there's an `LoginController.authfail` callback.  You have access to the username there, so you could persist the number of consecutive failed login attempts as a field in the session.  If it gets to 2, your `login/auth.gsp` page and `LoginController.auth` method could be updated to display this new question and process it on form submission.

Without knowing more specifics it's hard to tell if that will do everything you need, but it might be worth taking a look at.